# Nested increasing foreach loop

Tags: foreach, clojure, nested-loops

What is the idiomatic way to get something like that?

```
((fn [coll] (function-body)) [:a :b :c :d]) 
-> [[:a :b][:a :c][:a :d][:b :c][:b :d][:c :d]]
```

I can only do this in this way.

```
#(for [i (range (count %))
       j (range (inc i) (count %))]
   [(nth % i) (nth % j)])
```

But this is ugly, and at bigger collections very slow. I would like to avoid a loop/recur

Comment: I'd approach it with recursion, taking each key with `(first)` and calling some inner function over the rest with `(rest )` until `(= 0 (count (rest )))` (but I'm having a heck of time trying this in http://tryclj.com/, maybe this can help some else who knows more than I do.

Comment: What kind of collections is it being slow for, specifically? I'd expect reasonable performance with vectors, awful performance with lists.

Comment: vectors are fast. "nth" is slow, very slow.

Comment: @HuxleySource Running some timings on a million element vector `v`, I found that `(nth v 999999)` is as fast as `(v 999999)`.

Comment: @Thumbnail i agree, but iterating over collection is faster, than get each value by index.
`(for [elem (range 1000)]
  elem)`

is faster than

`(let [r (range 1000)]
  (for [idx r]
    (nth r idx)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion explicitly ...

```
(defn pairs [coll]
  (if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
    (lazy-cat (map #(vector x %) xs) (pairs xs))))
```

For example,

```
(pairs [:a :b :c :d])
; ([:a :b] [:a :c] [:a :d] [:b :c] [:b :d] [:c :d])
```

This is a lazy sequence. You can use `vec` to pour it into a vector if need be: a decision better left to the client, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lazy solution.

```
user> (def data [:a :b :c :d]) 
#'user/data
user> (defn loopy [data] 
         (lazy-seq (if (seq data) 
                       (cons (map #(vector (first data) %) (rest data)) 
                             (loopy (rest data))) 
                        nil))) 
#'user/loopy   

user> (apply concat (loopy data)) 
([:a :b] [:a :c] [:a :d] [:b :c] [:b :d] [:c :d])
```

this produces a lazy sequence where each element it a lazy sequence of creating a vector of the current element into a vector with each of the rest of the elements. The next segment is generated lazily when this segment is empty by the call to `(apply concat )`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an **ugly** pipeline that solves the problem. I don't find it much elegant but I haven't been able to beautify it.

```
(->> [:a :b :c :d] 
     (iterate rest) 
     (take-while not-empty) 
     (mapcat (fn [[f & r]] (map #(vector f %) r)))
     vec)
```

Let's analyze the function in the mapcat when given list `[:a :b :c :d]`. It computes all vectors with first element `:a` and second element succesive elements taken from `[:b :c :d], that is`([:a :b] [:a :c] [:a :d])`.

The first part of the pipeline, constructs the sequence of all the rests od the original vector `([:a :b :c :d](:b :c :d)(:c :d)(:d) () () () ...)` which is stopped at the first empty rest.

Then the mapcat plugs this list in the combining function described before, and the vec at the end, converts the sequence into a vector.

This can be more readable by introducing some auxiliar functions:

```
(defn rests [coll] 
  (take-while not-empty (iterate rest coll)))

(defn pairfirst [[f & r]] 
  (map #(vector f %) r))

(defn pairs [coll]
  (mapcat pairfirst (rests coll)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is along the lines of Juan Manuel's answer, I find it a bit more readable using list comprehension for the last part. The anonymous function generates the pairs `[(first s) x]`l for all the elements in `(rest s).`

```
(defn pairs [xs]
   (->> xs
       (iterate rest)
       (take-while seq)
       (mapcat #(for [x (rest %)]
                  [(first %) x]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`for` is already lazy](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for), and [`filter` is too](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter). So one way to do this, if the elements have a natural order, is to produce the cartesian product, and then filter on sort order.

```clj
(defn pairs [c]
  (->> (for [x c, y c] [x y])
       (filter #(apply <= %))))

(def c (range 0 1e7))

(time (nth (pairs c) 0))    ;; ~ 0.07 ms
(time (nth (pairs c) 1e4))  ;; ~ 6 ms
(time (nth (pairs c) 1e7))  ;; ~ 2600 ms
```

I think your use of `nth` might be slowing the collection iteration down:

```clj
(def pairs2
  #(for [i (range (count %))
         j (range (inc i) (count %))]
     [(nth % i) (nth % j)]))

(def c (range 0 1e7))

(time (nth (pairs2 c) 0))    ;; ~ 960 ms
(time (nth (pairs2 c) 1e4))  ;; ~ 1514 ms
(time (nth (pairs2 c) 1e7))  ;; ~ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```